# How can one hide a show all button after loading all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$("table > tbody > tr").hide().slice(0, 5).show();
$(".show-all").on("click", function()
  $("tbody > tr", $(this).prev()).show();
});
```

// The Button//
Show all

Comment: Include some html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("table > tbody > tr").hide().slice(0, 5).show();
$(".show-all").on("click", function()
  $("tbody > tr", $(this).prev()).show();
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the smoothness I would add a callback function to the show function. So when all the items are shown then the button will disappear.

```
$("table > tbody > tr").hide().slice(0, 5).show();
$(".show-all").on("click", function()
let that = this;
  $("tbody > tr", $(this).prev()).show(function(){
that.hide()
})
);

});
```